# Box2D cheching if object is colliding

Tags: libgdx, box2d, collision-detection

I want to check, if player is grounded, but I would like to avoid creating my own contact listener and creating filters. Is there a way to do it in LibGDX & Box2D without them?

Comment: There's pretty much no way I can think of detecting whether or not something is grounded without a contact listener. Someone who knows more about box2d might come along and prove me wrong, but it seems like an unnecessary restriction. Is there any particular reason why you won't want to use one?

Comment: I do not want to unnecessarily complicate my game.

Comment: Adding a contact listener is only one more class, and it'll make things less complex than using weird workarounds that intentionally avoid it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for assuring me. I will get into creating a new contact listener.